# Python Click Module Dict Return Value

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

In the documentation the usage of the click module is this way:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('tgt')
@click.argument('fun')
def main(tgt, fun):
    #stuff here
```

How can I pass a dictionary which contains all arguments that need to be passed to the main function instead of passing each argument separately, i.e:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('tgt')
@click.argument('fun')
def main(my_dict):
    print my_dict['tgt']
    print my_dict['fun']
    #stuff here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do -

```
def main(**kargs):
```

'kargs' will be a dictionary which will be having all the arguments.